Use 'order by' as parameter in custom SQLAlchemy query fails
I have been running this custom query which works against Postgres db and Python:
from sqlalchemy import text, bindparam 
sql = text("""
                   select t.column1, t.column2
                        from table1 t
                        where t.column3 = :which_column"""
                              )
    
    sql_params = {'which_column': variable}
    sql_query = sql.bindparams(bindparam('which_column'))
    sql_response = session.execute(sql_query, sql_params)

However, when trying to use this query including 'order by' and 'ASC' or 'DESC' as new parameters, it fails:
sql = text("""
               select t.column1, t.column2
                    from table1 t
                    where t.column3 = :which_column
                    order by :order_by :sort""")

sql_params = {'which_column': variable,
               'order_by': variable2,
                'sort': variable3}                             }
sql_query = sql.bindparams(bindparam('which_column'),
            bindparam('order_by'),
            bindparam('sort'))


Error negotiating with database: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near "'asc'"

The problem is that the 'order_by' and 'sort' parameters are inserted into single quotes.
e.g.: order by 'column1' 'asc'
My attempts using literal_column() and literal from sqlalchemy docs don't work in this context.

As has been noted here and elsewhere, query parameters are used to specify column values. They are not used to specify column names, table names, SQL keywords, etc..
If you want to use code to control such things without resorting to dynamic SQL (and its attendant risk of SQL injection annoyances) you can use SQLAlchemy Core to construct your query:
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table, create_engine, select

engine = create_engine("postgresql://scott:tiger@192.168.0.199/test")

query_options = {"order_by": "column2", "sort": "desc"}

t = Table("table1", MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)

qry = select(t.c.column1, t.c.column2)
order_by_col = t.c[query_options["order_by"]]
if query_options["sort"] == "desc":
    order_by_col = order_by_col.desc()
qry = qry.order_by(order_by_col)

print(qry.compile(engine))
"""
SELECT table1.column1, table1.column2 
FROM table1 ORDER BY table1.column2 DESC
"""


In any case, how the insert of a literal value from a variable could be inserted into the string query?

Dynamic SQL → string formatting → f"… ORDER BY {order_by} {sort}". Use at your own risk.
